# Issues with PDF Parsing in XML (Aspose) - Object Number and EOL Marker

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I am using the Aspose library to parse a PDF file represented in XML format, and I am encountering some issues related to object numbering and EOL markers. The XML snippet looks like this:

```
  <Compliance Name="Log" Operation="Validation" Target="PDF/A-2B">
<Version>1.0</Version>
<Copyright>Copyright (c) 2001-2018 Aspose Pty Ltd. All Rights Reserved.</Copyright>
<Date>05/03/2024 15:54:16</Date>
<File Version="1,7" Pages="1">
    <Security/>
    <Catalog/>
    <Header/>
    <Fonts/>
    <trailer/>
    <Metadata/>
    <objects>
        <Problem Severity="Error" Clause="6.1.8" ObjectID="5" Convertable="True">Object number not followed by EOL marker</Problem>
        <Problem Severity="Error" Clause="6.1.8" ObjectID="5" Convertable="True">Object number and generation number not separated by single white-space</Problem>
        <Problem Severity="Error" Clause="6.1.8" ObjectID="5" Convertable="True">Generation number and generation number not separated by single white-space</Problem>
    </objects>
    <xObjects/>
    <actions/>
</File>
```

I am specifically having trouble with the "Object number not followed by EOL marker" issue using Aspose. Has anyone using Aspose encountered a similar problem while parsing PDFs in XML format? Any insights or suggestions on how to address this with Aspose would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!